# Updates only the current page in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Using ViewPager. To couse of method notifyDataSetChanged() for adapter PageStateAdapter, updates all pages. How it can updates only the current page in ViewPager?

onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
    MyPageAdapter myAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), true);
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) myView.findViewById(R.id.my_pager);
    myPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}
```

PageAdapter:

```
//
    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private MyFragment[] fragments;


        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

            fragments = new MyFragment[] { new Fragment1(), new Fragment2(), new Fragment3() };
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            return fragments[i];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.length;
        }

        @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {

        }
    }
//
```

Comment: Use `setTag()` method to set tag for particular page and then use `findViewWithTag()` to identify page.

Comment: I Would be very grateful if you wrote the code to do this, I has already spent a lot of time, but do not understand how it is written. Please.

Answer (score 0):

To find current page add `addTab()` method in your `adapter` class. In that method set `Tag.`

```
   public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

then on `TabSelected` you can check for `Tag`

```
   @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i=0; i<mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

For more information you can visit [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)  and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) link